# Проблема с jquery json parse

Tags: jquery, json

При попытке вывести полученный json jquery валится с ошибкой -

> jquery.min.js:2
>   Uncaught TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for '2520' in.

Вот json:

```
[
{
   name: "ААА АААААА",
   lat: "43.1662323931",
   lng: "131.923339512",
   status: null
},
{
   name: "ВЫАЫВА ААААА АААА",
   lat: "43.09832378",
   lng: "131.92623462",
   status: null
},
{
   name: "ЗЗЗЗЗЗ ЗЗЗЗ ХЗЗЗ",
   lat: "43.16569999995",
   lng: "131.94030216",
   status: null
}

]
```

Вот как пытаюсь вывести значения:

```
$.ajax({
        url:'some.php',
        success:function(data){
            var dataPlacemark=JSON.parse(data);
            $.each(data,function(i,item){
                console.log('Статья: id = '+data.name );
            })
        }

    });
```

Comment: в примере указан не JSON а массив объектов

Answer (score 1):

В примере указан не JSON а массив объектов. 
Если предположить что это уже полученные данные

```
let data =  [{
     name: "ААА АААААА",
     lat: "43.1662323931",
     lng: "131.923339512",
     status: null
   },
   {
     name: "ВЫАЫВА ААААА АААА",
     lat: "43.09832378",
     lng: "131.92623462",
     status: null
   },
   {
     name: "ЗЗЗЗЗЗ ЗЗЗЗ ХЗЗЗ",
     lat: "43.16569999995",
     lng: "131.94030216",
     status: null
   }];
```

Тогда для вывода в цикле используем конструкцию:

```
  $.each(data, function(i,item){
     console.log('Статья: id = '+item.name )
  })
```

Comment: Я пробовал данную конструкцию ранее, но к сожалению не получил результата,валится та же ошибка

Answer (score 1):

Не надо парсить `JSON`, если это конечно он.

```js
$.ajax({
  url: 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users',
  success: function(data) {
    //var dataPlacemark=JSON.parse(data); // No need to JSON.parse
    $.each(data, function(i, item) {
      console.log('Статья: id = ' + data[i].name);
    })
  }

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Решил следующим способом:

```
$.ajax({
        url:'some.php',
        success:function(data){
             var sample= JSON.parse(data);
                $.each(sample,function(){
                console.log('Имя  = '+ this.name );
                console.log('lat = '+ this.lat );
                console.log('lang = '+ this.lng );}
});
```